# How to compare time part of datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, compare

Let's say we have

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("2012/12/12 15:00:00.000");
```

and

```
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("2012/12/12 15:03:00.000");
```

How to compare it in C# and say which time is "is later than"?

Comment: Your question does not match your question title. Do you want to compare the DateTime, or just the time portion of a DateTime?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use the [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property and use the [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare.aspx) against it.

```
TimeSpan.Compare(t1.TimeOfDay, t2.TimeOfDay)
```

Per the documentation:

```
-1  if  t1 is shorter than t2.
0   if  t1 is equal to t2.
1   if  t1 is longer than t2.
```

Comment: @Peretz no disrespect intended, but this answer should tell you everything you need to know without a code sample...

Comment: @Peretz I have updated my answer with a code snippet and how to use the results.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter who has taken up a grudge against me, could you please explain why this was downvoted along with about 10 other answers of mine. Serial downvoting is automatically fixed by the system BTW, so everything should end up restored...was it really worth it...

Answer (score 37):

The `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==` operators all work directly on `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` objects. So something like this works:

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse("2012/12/12 15:00:00.000");
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("2012/12/12 15:03:00.000");

if(t1.TimeOfDay > t2.TimeOfDay) {
    //something
}
else {
    //something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess...was something like DateTime vs. TimeSpan such a dealbreaker that it warranted a downvote in the first place though? I think not.

Comment: It did not answer the question as posted, so yes typically that is what downvotes are for. Also, you forgot to mention == works also.

Comment: We are really beating a dead horse here but you are obviously caught up in these silly details (also with @mgnoonan). There were some edits in between the time the OP was put up, my original answer, your answer, my edited answer, etc. Exercise sound judgement before down-voting every interpretation of the question that does not match your own.

Comment: `How to compare time part of datetime` and  `time is "is later than"` both refer to time . I am just responding to comments/questions at this point /shrug

Answer (score 6):

Use [the `DateTime.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) method:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
```

**Edit:** If you just want to compare the times, and ignore the date, you can use the `TimeOfDay` as others have suggested. If you need something less fine grained, you can also use the `Hour` and `Minute` properties.

Comment: A date is nothing more than a realization of time. Ticks, for example, are the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. So comparing two dates is really just comparing the difference in Ticks. The time comparison is implicit.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking for just the Time comparison. If you compare the full tick, then it will not test if 6AM is later than 5 AM for example, which is what seems to be implied by the question

Comment: It's a Date**TIME** object! Comparing the two automatically tells you which is greater!

Comment: Yes, but Jan 2 5AM is is greater than Jan 1 6 AM, but 5AM is not greater than 6 AM. That is the difference between comparing a full DateTime versus only its Time portion

Comment: OP just says "which is later", which I took to mean empirically. He's free to select any answer that fits his purpose.

Comment: You are correct, there is some room for interpretation of what the OP wants so I will leave the selection up to him. If you want to edit your post, I will remove my downvote for that reason

Comment: Looking at the title alone, you may be right, he's after the time portion specifically. I must have read past that too quickly. Ah well, my answer stands.

Answer (score 4):

See these examples, which explain the time zone conversion in C#.

```
var startTime = new System.TimeSpan(23,0,0);
var endTime = new System.TimeSpan(02,0,0);

var startDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Day, startTime.Hours, startTime.Minutes, startTime.Seconds);
var endDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Day, endTime.Hours, endTime.Minutes, endTime.Seconds);

var cetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
var startConvertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(startDateTime, cetTimeZone);
var endConvertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(endDateTime, cetTimeZone);

Console.WriteLine(startConvertedTime.TimeOfDay);
Console.WriteLine(endConvertedTime.TimeOfDay);

var currentTime = new TimeSpan(03,0,0);
Console.WriteLine(currentTime);

Console.WriteLine(currentTime >= startConvertedTime.TimeOfDay && currentTime <= endConvertedTime.TimeOfDay);
```