# How to set custom format to DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I want to know how can I format `DateTime.Now` in this same format `Thursday 03:00 PM` so that I can compare it to my custom format date time value,

I am trying to create a simple scheduling system, that if a specific date time will be equivalent to current date time a code will run under it but I am stuck in comparing my custom dates to current date time

```
string[] schedule = { "Thursday 2:47 PM", "Thursday 2:50 PM", "Thursday 2:55 PM" };
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateValue;
            foreach (var i in schedule)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(i, out dateValue))
                {
                    if (dateValue == DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        //do something here
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

Comment: what error are you getting? even your schedule array doesn't contains any date, it has only time.

Comment: Well you have to specifically compare the relevant parts like day of the week and Time of Day since there is no date information you have in the string to be parsed

Comment: Well DateTime.Now includes also seconds, so comparing fixed date with an ever changing date like DateTime.Now is practically inattainable

Comment: @Steve, I think i just need to compare the current Time and that time must be like schedule format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `dateValue.ToString("dddd hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`

- **dddd** - The full name of the day of the week.
- **hh** - The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
- **mm** - The minute, from 00 through 59.
- **tt** - The AM/PM designator.

You can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more info.

Comment: What's the reason for recommending `CreateSpecificCulture` instead of `new CultureInfo` or `GetCultureInfo`?

Comment: If `CreateSpecificCulture` will fail to create instance of type `CultureInfo` for "en-X" it will try again to do create an instance for "en" culture.

Answer (score 2):

It should work this way.

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(i, out dateValue))
{
  if (dateValue.ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.ToString("dd hh:mm tt"))
  {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

**dd** tells to show the current day. **hh** displays the hours and **mm** the minutes. I left **ss** for seconds because it seems you don't need it. Through **tt** *PM* or *AM* will get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) Method to convert strings from custom format to DateTime

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare `Time` value with `DateTime` value. I think you just want to compare that Time values of your `array` to `current` time value, in that case you can compare time part of the dates.

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(i, out dateValue))
{
  if (dateValue.ToShortTimeString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString())
  {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check here for [Date Time Example](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) or [Date Time Format](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For)

For example

```
MyString = MyDateTime.ToString("dddd  hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert time in schedule string array into DateTime.

Link about DateTime styles: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

After that, you need to compare only time part of 2 dates. Took the answer from here: [How to compare time part of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290187/how-to-compare-time-part-of-datetime)

So, finally your code will be something like this:

```
string[] schedule = { "Thursday 2:47 PM", "Thursday 2:50 PM", "Thursday 2:55 PM" };
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dateValue;
    foreach (var i in schedule)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(i, "dddd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (dateValue.DayOfWeek == currentDate.DayOfWeek && dateValue.TimeOfDay == currentDate.TimeOfDay)
            {
                //do something here
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Of course, you can convert DateTime.Now to a string of valid format (as in your string array) but I think that it's wrong. If you want to check that your date is earlier or later than current date, you will have to rewrite your code.