# Compare 2 strings of time in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

So I've got a string 00:00:15:185 which I need to tell is greater than 15 seconds.

Time format is HH:m:ss:FFF

This is clearly longer than 15 seconds but I can't compare it properly.

Current code is this:

```
value = "00:00:15:185";    
if (DateTime.Parse(value) > DateTime.Parse("00:00:15:000"){
    //do stuff
}
```

It's giving exceptions when I run it all the time and the program doesn't work when it should

Comment: Possible duplicate from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290187/how-to-compare-time-part-of-datetime - better use DateTime.Compare or TimeSpan.Compare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string doesn't represent a time, but an *amount* of time. We have `TimeSpan` for that.

```
var value = "00:00:15:185";
if (TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, @"hh\:mm\:ss\:FFF", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of that and it turns out it was only partly this at fault but another issue. So thank you for helping me work out where the fault was.

Answer (score 1):

Another option(apart from @rob 's answer), use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
    var value = "00:00:15:185";    

    if (DateTime.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > 
        DateTime.ParseExact("00:00:15:000", "HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        // logic here.  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
String result = time.ToString("HH:mm ");

 DateTime firstTimr = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["shift_start_time"].ToString(), "HH:mm:tt", null);
 String firstTimr1 = firstTimr.ToString("HH:mm ");
DateTime lastTime = DateTime.ParseExact(reader["Shift_last_time"].ToString(), "HH:mm:tt", null);
String lastTime1 = lastTime.ToString("HH:mm ");

if (DateTime.Parse(result) >= DateTime.Parse(firstTimr1) && (DateTime.Parse(result) <= DateTime.Parse(lastTime1)))
                    {
                       `enter code here` MessageBox.Show("First Shit");

                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.