# How do I code Time > 8:15

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I code Time greater than `8:15`?

I want to to have a button with a condition that if the time greater than `8:15` it will not be visible.

Comment: 8:15 on the client or on the server?

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290222/5444143)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare time part of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290187/how-to-compare-time-part-of-datetime)

Comment: If *what* time? You've referred to "if the time" - do you mean the current time? In which time zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `inputTime` be the input time that you have, then you can use the following code for comparison:

```
DateTime inputTime = DateTime.Now; // initializing with current DateTime
bool isGreater = inputTime.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(8,15,0);
if(isGreater)
{
    // code here time is Greater
}
```

Here the `TimeOfDay` property will give you the current time(is of type `TimeSpan`), it is directly comparable with another `TimeSpan` object, so we can make use of the Constructor of the `TimeSpan` class to create a Timespan equivalent to `8:15`. Now the variable `isGreater` will have the comparison result. Take a Look at this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6VZJ8S)